# show data in ascending or descending manner

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

We are using JSF and primefaces to develop application, i have a scenario where it will show data in the table and on click on any column header the data should get sorted either ascending/descending. BUt problem is the sort functionality is not working nor throwing any kind of errors to debug. Below is the code i have written:

Please let me know do i need to include any other attributes to make sorting work.
Thanks.

Comment: What about removing `sortMode="multiple"` ?

Comment: Omar -- initially i tried it, it didn't work , then i kept that attribute even its not working.

Comment: The use of non EL expressions in the sortBy-FilterBy fields has been made deprecated in PrimeFaces5, it was only implemented in 4. What version of PF are you using?

Comment: @VeenarM - primefaces4.0 is the version.how can i proceed to make it work??

Answer (score 0):

Change your columns like this

```
     <p:column id="NumberCol" sortBy="#{OrderInfo.orderNumber}"      headerText="Order Number" >  
        <h:outputText value="#{OrderInfo.orderNumber}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column id="NumberCol" sortBy="#{OrderInfo.Number}" headerText="Number" >  
        <h:outputText value="#{OrderInfo.Number}" />
    </p:column>
```

This should work.

Hope this helps

Comment: Srikanth Ganji -- No its not working, i tried initially in the same manner and it didn't work, retried it not working.